# UWP application referencing .NETStandard 2.0 PCL fails to load assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on a Xamarin cross platform application, and my iOS and Android apps work fine but when I launch my UWP app, I have the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I tried getting rid of package.config but it didn't work, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of UWP you are targeting? .NET Standard 2.0 is only supported on latest UWP release (Fall Creators Update), so you cannot get it working on previous UWP releases.

Answer (score 0):

> my iOS and Android apps work fine but when I launch my UWP app, I have the following exception:

If you attempt to build and run at this point iOS and Android should work without issue. UWP will most likely compile but will raise an exception `Could not load file or assembly` at runtime.

You could make the changes manually to the csproj file. Right-click the UWP project in Solution Explorer and select unload project. Next, right-click on the UWP project node and select Edit MySecondXamarinFormsApp.UWP.csproj.

Add a new `PropertyGroup` like the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Now you can right-click on the UWP project in Solution Explorer and select Reload project. Now you should be able to run the UWP project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this but unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Please refer to this [blog](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/09/13/Getting-Started-Xamarin-Forms-with-NET-Standard-20.aspx). It works in my side.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had to work on other projects, I followed these steps but I still have the exception, unfortunately.